# Development of an API

Tags: android, cross-platform, desktop-application

I have a project to do at school, it's about developing an API to link three applications from different platforms to a single database. It will be a desktop, mobile and web application. But problem, I've never developed an API and I don't know where to start. I would like you to tell me how to do it (which language to use, which software I need and if you can advise me on specific courses), or at least give me indications on how to search. I heard that we could develop some with Python which is a language that I use often, so if there are indications that can go in this direction as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on knowledge about python i recommend to use Flask framework to create your api and you can find a lot of youtube videos can help you
i hope that i was helpful for you good luck

Comment: Thanks mate, I'll do more research on that. Thank you so much.

Comment: you'r welcome  you can rate my anwser and thanks a lot